# Are sliding external doors "French windows"?

Tags: word-request

I was trying to translate *portafinestra* in English, and I think I found the correct term (*French window*) whose definition seems to match with what I would define *portafinestra*: "each of a pair of casement windows extending to the floor in an outside wall, serving as a window and door."

Can I call *French window* those doors that are opened by sliding them? If it is not the right term, what is a term that I could use also for sliding doors facing on an outside wall?

Comment: You can always apply the [Google images test](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1186&bih=819&q=french+windows&oq=french+windows&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1748.6161.0.6296.20.13.3.4.4.0.201.1644.4j8j1.13.0...0.0...1ac.1.4.img.zBD7hK019dw)

Comment: For some of the images shown in that page, I would use the term _window_, not _French window_.

Comment: I can’t resist mentioning the humourist Gerard Hoffnung, who spoke of receiving a letter from an Austrian hotel proprietor about the attractions of his establishment, which included a French widow in every bedroom, affording delightful prospects.

Comment: kiamlaluno: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply that link would answer everything. I only meant to share a hint that can get us started in the right direction. If I'm unsure I'm using the right term for something, I'll sometimes do a Google images search to check (but it's not infallible: see [this ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68872) and [this Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1186&bih=819&q=puce+dress&oq=puce+dress&gs_l=img.3...3094.4682.0.4976.10.8.0.2.0.0.123.745.7j1.8.0...0.0...1ac.1.4.img.TK7-PpxKRY0)).

Comment: @J.R. I understood the link purpose; I was saying that what shown in some images is what in Italian I would call _window_, for example in the case of a window that is as wide as the wall is, but that I could not use as door. I don't know if that means a _French window_ doesn't match exactly what in Italian would be a _portafinestra_, though.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window): "A _French window_ (when hinged _French door_) is a large door-sized lattice light, typically set in pairs or multiples thereof. Known as _porte-fenêtre_ in France and _portafinestra_ in Italy, they often overlook a terrace." But then there's [this](http://www.ehow.com/info_12136360_french-casement-window.html#ixzz2Lii8wgLj): "French doors are elegant additions in residential homes. The French casement window resembles a French door, opening outward and inward rather than up or down." Seems like there's room for ambiguity no matter what.

Comment: Sometimes "French window" means a window that opens like a French door, which is why "French door" is sometimes used in place of "French window". _What a pane in the glass!_

Comment: @J.R. Oh yes, that is another difference I noticed between Italy, and the U.S.A.: In an Italian house, you open a window by pulling, or pushing it.

Comment: As a Br Eng speaker, I've always understood 'French door' to be the American term and 'French window' the British, for the thing pictured on the right hand side in J.R.'s answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of factors at work here.

As Barrie mentioned, doors that open to the backyard are called patio doors. Patio doors can have two styles: sliding, or hinged.

In the U.S., the sliding style doors are often called "sliding glass doors." The term "French doors" is used for double doors that open outward or inward, particularly when they are made of paned glass.

I found these two images on a [retail web site](http://www.lowes.com/Windows-Doors/Doors/Patio-Doors-Accessories/_/N-1z11ppg/pl):

[image: patio doors]

The door on the left is listed as a **Sliding Patio Door**; the one on the right is a **French Inswing Patio Door**. However, in day-to-day conversation, I'd probably refer them as "the sliding glass door" or "the French doors" – although either of them could be called "the patio door."

With all that said, though, I still found a [website](http://www.milgard.com/catalog/doors/style/french-sliding/series/tuscany/french-sliding.asp) that sells "French-Style Sliding Doors," which sounds like an oxymoron to me.

Comment: Would _glass doors_ be understood to mean both the type of doors? I remember that at first I translated _portafinestra_ with _glass doors_, and the friend of mine (born in the USA) understood what I meant.

Comment: A _glass door_ could be any door made out glass, including a [glass storm door](http://www.windowworldlansing.com/images/storm-door.jpg), a [glass entry door](http://www.berkeleymills.com/Catalog/Product/Images/Photo_154_425_3.png), or the [glass door to a commercial establishment](http://www.a1qualityglass.net/A-1_images/glass-entry-door.jpg). We're dealing with a tricky mixed taxonomy here, because there's the function of the door (entry, patio, storm, shower, interior), the material (wood, metal, vinyl, glass), the style (hinged or sliding), and the type of glass (paned, stained, etc.)

Comment: Supposing to be at somebody's home, would _glass door_ be understood to mean also _sliding glass door_, or would I see the owner of the house going to open the entrance door to check the glass storm door?

Comment: If my house had a glass storm door in the front, and a sliding glass door in the back, and I gave you a key so you could get inside, I would not say "this is a key to the glass door," because that would be ambiguous. I'd probably either say, "This is the key to the storm door in the front," or, "This is the key to the sliding glass door in the back," because _storm door_ and _sliding glass door_ are two of the more common ways to refer to those two doors.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, sliding doors of the kind you describe are referred to as *patio doors* when they open onto an external paved area.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for common usage in the US, but in the England, we used to just have doors, which were mostly solid wood and opened all the way to the ground, and windows, which were glazed and didn't.  Some hundreds of years ago, however, it was noted that in France, some rooms had windows (with glazed panes much like ours) that extended all the way to the ground.  These "long" windows, often be in pairs (and only ever of the hinged type) would provide access to the balcony or the garden and facilitate a nice air flow in warmer weather.
Architects in England started to incorporate the full-length hinged windows into their designs and they were referred to as "french windows", but only used in place of a window - the main front door of a house would still be largely solid wood.
The term "french door" is meaningless - unless you mean a door in France.  If you are talking about a pair of hinged, glazed doors, say just that.  In England, we should say "french windows" (or "patio doors" if they slide).